# Using TestCaseSource to get TestCases with parameters

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

To test a bunch of NUnit-Tests, I want to read all test cases out of a textfile.

This textfile looks like:
line 0: "testcasename, param0, param1"
line 1: "testcasename, param0, param1, param 2,..."

There are different test cases with a different method signature.

My NUnit-Call looks like:

```
[Test, TestCaseSource("TestSelection")]             
public void Module(String testPath, String testFile, int version)
{
   Test1(testPath, testFile, true, version);
}


public static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> TestSelection()
{
   var path = @"C:\path\TestCases.txt";
            
   foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(path))
   {
     yield return new TestCaseData(line.Split(','));
   }
            
}
```

I want to get a test case for each line in a textfile. Each test case should contain the parameters which are within the same line, seperated by a comma.
The parameters have to be of the correct type. So, even if the whole line is read as a string, a digit should be an int within the TestCaseData.

Answer (score 2):

Your TestCaseSource method is providing test cases with three string arguments. But your test method requires two strings and an int. You are aware of this and say that "the digit should be an int" but there's no code to do that conversion.

When you create a `TestCaseData` item, it must match the method signature or only require standard implicit conversions. So, for example, you could pass an `int` to a method requiring a `long` but not the reverse. You definitely cannot expect a `string` to be converted to an `int` unless you do it yourself.

In addition, according to the layout you gave, the file lines contain the name of a testcase followed by the parameters. Your code does not take that layout into account, but assumes that the entire line consists of parameters.

Here's a modified version of your TestCaseSource method, which solves some of those problems. It may not be complete, because I'm making some guesses about what you want to accomplish. It's entirely missing any error checks as well.

```
public static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> TestSelection()
{
   var path = @"C:\path\TestCases.txt";
        
   foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(path))
   {
     var data = line.Split(',');
     // Ignoring data[0]
     yield return new TestCaseData(data[1], data[2], int.Parse(data[3]));
   }    
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. I will add a second question where I try tro clarify my problem. But why I have to ignore the data[0]? Should the name of the TestCase not be part of the TestCaseData?

Comment: If you intend to use the name, then of course you can't ignore it. But you can't use it as one of the arguments to TestCaseData because it's not an argument to your test method. You can use a TestCaseData property to set the name of the test.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify my problem here is another description.

My main source of information is a textfile, where all of my TestCases are stored.
An example of such a textfile could be:

line 0 : |"Testpath0", "Testname0", "param0"|
line 1 : |"Testpath1", "Testname1", "param0", "param1", "param2"|
and so on.

Important is the fact that each line could contain a different amount of parameters(of course I have to write the correct testmethod for each amount of params).
Another fact: The first two information (testpath and testname) are Strings, all the other parameters are Ints.

Now I want to read that lines and convert them into TestCases. Helpful should be TestCaseSource.

My current method to do that looks like:

```
public static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> TestData()
        {
            var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(
                @"C:\pathTestCases.txt"));
            
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var list = new List<Object>();
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                var values = line.Split(',');
                
                for(int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                {
                    if(i == 0 || i == 1)
                    {
                        String arg = values[i];
                        list.Add(arg);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int arg = Int32.Parse(values[i]);
                        list.Add(arg);
                    }
                }
                yield return new TestCaseData(list);
                
            }
            
        }
```

The TestMethods are another part of the problem, but first of all I have to read that data properly.

If I run this it does not work. Its kind of frustrating

Comment: It's confusing to have your question restated as an answer to your original question. Can't you simply edit the original question and remove this?